# Flat hose wrapped around a cylinder

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction

It was always taught to me that friction is independent of surface area. I was recently made aware that that is only partially true. My question is: would a layflat hose and a rope of equal weight and diameter produce the same frictional force when wrapped around a pole?

Comment: the materials in contact have an impact on the friction. look up coefficients of static friction or see the chart here https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html

Comment: Related - It is not a difference in area rather one of a difference in the normal force https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19951/104696

Answer (score -2):

The rope around the pole is going to generaly produce more friction. Tho this has nothing to do with surface area,since at both situations the surface area is the same. So as u have always been taught friction has to do with the normal force. While a lay flat rope can only produce normal from gravity ,the pole one can get tight under the right conditions and what ever is pulling on it going to create more normal force.